# How can I populate a field of the polylines to indicate if they intersect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, intersection

I have two feature classes, one ploylines, one a buffer.  How can I populate a field of the polylines to indicate if they intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have a field created, use 'Select by location' from the selection menu, and select all the features that intersect the other feature, then open the attribute table and use the field calculator to populate a "yes" value for the selected features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Spatial Join (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to write to attributes how many times a polyline intersects a polygon feature.  Consider the following sample data set comprised of polylines and polygons.  From the "join_count" field, you can see polyline 1 intersects 9 polygon features, polyline 2 intersects 4 polygon features and line 3 intersects 0 times.

[image]

[image]